# How to get a list of Photoset primary photos using FlickrNet

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, flickr

I've been working on a web app to pull in the primary photos for a list of photosets in a Flickr account using FlickrNet https://flickrnet.codeplex.com/.  I can pull in the title and description of these photosets but there doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to pull a list of the primary photos.  Does anyone have any suggestions or some example code of pulling these from Flickr?

```
Public Shared Function GetPhotoSetsByUser(userId As String) As PhotosetCollection
    Dim flickr As New Flickr(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("apiKey"), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("shardSecret"))

    'Limit photosets to 10
    Return flickr.PhotosetsGetList(userId, 1, 10)

End Function
```

Above is the code I have used to retrieve a list of the photosets.  From this I can pull out the title and description.

Answer (score 0):

There's next to no info on this out there but after trawling one of the discussion pages I came across .PhotosetSmallUrl. This gives me the URL.